# Bind9 works internally and as forward but not reversing internet dns

Tags: bind

I setup a Bind9 to be my network DNS. I'm using it as both a forwarder and an internal IP resolution.

The problem is that I cannot reverse DNS from internet IPs.

For example, I have a proxy server that shows all domains I have an open connection, but after starting to use bind9, it only shows IP addresses and not domains.

I am not trying to resolve local ips; I want to resolve internet ips.

I did a test, as you can see below:

```
 C:\Users\ivola>nslookup youtube.com ns.lan
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.232

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    youtube.com
Addresses:  2a03:2880:f10e:83:face:b00c:0:25de
          199.96.58.105




C:\Users\ivola>nslookup 199.96.58.105 ns.lan
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.232

*** Unknown: can't find 199.96.58.105: Non-existent domain
```

My configuration is very basic:

> options {
>
> ```
>     directory "/var/cache/bind";
>
>     empty-zones-enable no;
>     allow-query { any; };
>      forwarders {
>             8.8.4.4;        //google
>             1.1.1.1;        //cloudflare
>             8.8.8.8;        //google
>             94.247.43.254;  //open nic
>             194.36.144.87;  //open nic
>             129.134.30.12;  //whatsapp
>      };
> ```

> ```
>     dnssec-validation auto;
> ```

> ```
>     zone "lan" IN {
>             type master;
>             file "/etc/bind/lan.zone";
> ```
>
> };

lan.zone:

> $TTL 2d
>
> $ORIGIN lan.
>
> @                       IN      SOA     ns.lan.
> mail.hotmail.com.  (
> 2023111002      ;serial
> 12h     ; refressh
> 15m     ; retry
> 3w      ; expire
> 2h      ; minimum ttl
> )
>
> ```
>                     IN      NS      ns.lan. ns                      IN      A       192.168.50.232 homeserver              IN      A
> ```
>
> 192.168.50.11 openwrt                 IN      A       192.168.50.1 qbittorrent.direct      IN      A       192.168.50.11 direct
> IN      A       192.168.50.251 clash                   IN      A
> 192.168.50.11 yacd.clash              IN      A       192.168.50.11
> *.homeserver            IN      A       192.168.50.11 esxi                    IN      A       192.168.50.10 extra                   IN      A
> 192.168.50.232 umbrel                  IN      A       192.168.50.232 ax3                     IN      A       192.168.60.1

Comment: What does the log say, both during bind startup and when you run your query?

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting of your question so it shows the content of your zone file with correct linebreaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're aware that `199.96.58.105` doesn't have a valid reverse DNS entry?

```
$ nslookup 199.96.58.105
** server can't find 105.58.96.199.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Try `nslookup 8.8.8.8 ns.lan`. That should return `dns.google.` as answer.

Comment: I think that this is the case; some IPs just don't have a reversed domain. Unfortunately, I tested some, and they didn't work. for example, extra.com, but Google is working as you stated.